# How to write superscript in android?

Tags: android, html, xml, numbers

I am trying to write a subscript in android textview and this is the code that I am using.

```
txt.setText(String.valueOf((int)num) + (Html.fromHtml("<sup><small>2<small></sup>")));
```

When I am running this program, the 2 looks as the same as the other text from integer num.

Answer (score 1):

From what i see in your code, you didn't close the small tag. Just do this: `<small>2</small>`. Notice the "/" character in the second `</small>` tag.